# How do i generate ASCII visual from given JSON data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Is it possible to generate ASCII visual map using given JSON data using JS assuming one place can only have maximum 4 ways

want something like below

```
A=====B======C
      |
      D
```

```json
{
  "A": [ "B"],
  "B": [ "A", "C", "D"],
  "C": ["D"],
  "D": ["B"]
}
```

Below is what I tried

```js
const data = {
  "A": ["B"],
  "B": ["A", "C", "D"],
  "C": ["B"],
  "D": ["B"]
};

for (const location in data) {
  const neighbors = data[location];
  let line = location;
  for (const neighbor of neighbors) {
    line += '=====' + neighbor;
  }
  console.log(line);
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any `"|"` in your code

Comment: How would a more nested example look like? It is odd that the top level structure is a plain object, but the first level structure is array. What would be the third level structure if it were present?

Comment: its what i'm trying to do

Comment: If you are trying to do that, then please show your attempt?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how is your *example graph* related to the JSON you presented...

Comment: i can't figure out the way doing so

Comment: How is `"C": ["D"],` depicted as a connection in the graph?

Comment: This could have been a nice question if the example was consistent, and the effort did more than just concatenating all keys with `===`.

Comment: I’d recommend trying to use an existing tool rather than writing your own.

Comment: When you exhaust all alphabet letters, how are you accounting spaces or vertical diagram lines positions for possible multicharacter IDs?

Comment: What would be the output for `{ "A": ["B", "C", "D", "E"] }`? Or are arrays limited to **3** entries? Sorry this question is not clear. The rendering you provide does not correspond to the object, and there is no description that makes it all clear. I am voting to close it.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more detailed here, because the ascii graph you're showing and the string based relations you're showing don't match. B links to D, _and_ D links to B according to your string data, but your graph shows a single link between B and D. Also, before you reinvent the wheel: [have you searched](/help/how-to-ask) for libraries that already do this? Because I can guarantee you are not the first person in the history of JS to want text graphs.

Comment: If you do this, the question may survive: (1) explain what the JSON represents. It looks like the adjacency list for an *undirected* graph, but this is nowhere said. (2) "ways" is not a precise term. Do you mean "edges"? (3) Maximum number of nodes? (4) Can graph be disconnected? Then what is the output? (4) Is there a reason why horizontal lines are double, and vertical single? (5) Your attempt is hardly trying anything close. It just makes a single line for each node. Improve your attempt. (6) actively respond to queries for clarification.

Comment: Also, (7) how will a triangle be represented (edges A-B, B-C and C-A)?